# On reduction of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $d>0$. Let $I$ be an $\mathfrak m$-primary ideal of $R$ i.e. $\sqrt I =\mathfrak m$ .

How to show that there exists $x_1,...,x_d \in I$ such that for some $n \ge 1$, we have $I^{n+1}=I^n (x_1,...,x_d)$ ?

I am not even able to do the case $d=1$.

I know that for some $x_1,...,x_d\in R$ , we have $\sqrt {(x_1,...,x_d)}=\mathfrak m$, but that's not enough.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know Noether Normalization? If so, consider $S=R\oplus I\oplus I^2\oplus\cdots$ and apply it for $S/\mathfrak{m}S$.

Comment: @Mohan: I'm not sure how Noether normalisation on $S/\mathfrak m S$ would give what I want ... could you please elaborate ? Thanks

Comment: Choose $x_1,\ldots,x_d\in I$ so that their images in $S/\mathfrak{m}S$ give a Noether normalization. Use the fact that $S/\mathfrak{m}S$ is  a finite module over $R/\mathfrak{m}[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ to show what you want.